# AngularJS: Access parent form from ngForm?

Tags: angularjs, validation

Here is a typical example of AngularJS form validation via ngForm:

```
<form name="parentForm">
  <div ng-form="childForm">
    <input ... />
    <span class="error" ng-if="childForm.$invalid && (childForm.$dirty || parentForm.$submitted)">...</span>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

But what if you don't know the name `parentForm` or perhaps it's not in scope because `childForm` is in a directive? Is there a way to access it via `childForm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parent form is accessible from the child form via the `$$parentForm` property.

So your `ng-if` expression will be `childForm.$invalid && (childForm.$dirty || childForm.$$parentForm.$submitted)`

Note that this is available in Angular 1.3 and higher, not in 1.2.

Your `span` could be in a directive with an isolated scope, making the `$scope.childForm` `undefined`. As workaround you could set the form on the scope in your directive:

```
require: '^form',
link: function (formCtrl) {
  $scope[formCtrl.$name] = formCtrl;
}
```

Comment: Note that using any $$property is considered a bad practice as they represent private API and are subject to breaking changes between versions. I am in the same boat (ng-form wrapped in isolated directive that need access to the parent's form) and arriving at the same conclusion, unfortunately

Comment: Sure, the child-form should be separated from the parent form and this solution is hard to test as well. Apart from the usage of $$-properties this is a bad pattern, but the questioner is already doing it this way...